# manually committing offsets in kafka

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I have a list of offsets with their corresponding partition and I need to commit them manually.
To do so I am looping through the list and assigning partition to the consumer and then seeking to a particular offset.
then I am consuming the message and passing the ConsumerBulider to commit method.
Sometimes it executes smoothly but sometimes it throws "Local:Waiting for Coordinator" exception.
But in both the cases , when I try consuming messages afterwards I re-consume the same series of messages I already have committed or should I say I tried committing. Which means I never really could commit them :(

```
`

foreach (var item in cmdparamslist)
{
            Partition p = new Partition(Int16.Parse(item.PartitionID));
            TopicPartition tp = new 
TopicPartition(configuration.GetSection("KafkaSettings").GetSection("Topic").Value, p);
            Offset o = new Offset(long.Parse(item.Offset));
            TopicPartitionOffset tpo = new TopicPartitionOffset(tp, o);
            try
            {
                KafkaConsumer.Assign(tpo);
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                KafkaConsumer.Seek(tpo);
                var cr = KafkaConsumer.Consume(cts.Token);
                try
                {
                    KafkaConsumer.Commit(cr);
                }
                catch (TopicPartitionOffsetException e1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("exception " + e);
                }
                catch (KafkaException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("exception " + e);
                }
            }
            catch (KafkaException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("exception " + e);
            }
        }
        KafkaConsumer.Close();
    }
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("exception "+e);
}
}
```

Consumer / Client configuration:

```
    var conf = new ConsumerConfig
    {
        GroupId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        BootstrapServers = configuration.GetSection("KafkaSettings").GetSection("RemoteServers").Value,
        AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
        SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.Gssapi,
        SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslPlaintext,
        EnableAutoCommit = false
        //EnableAutoOffsetStore = false
    };`
```

I am using Confluent.Kafka 1.6.2 version and .net5

Could someone please help me ?